# Find out what is causing the ifc file to not complete importing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, ifc

When converting IFC data using the APS DerivativeAPI, the conversion fails if there is a sequence of "''," strings in the IFC data to be converted. For example, the following case.

#1078 = IFCPROPERTYLISTVALUE('property_data', '', (IFCTEXT('SPVER,10,\X2\4ED569D866F830D030FC30B830E730F330B330FC30C9\X0,,')), $);
#1079 = IFCPROPERTYLISTVALUE('table_data', '', (IFCTEXT('SPVER,10,\X2\4ED569D866F830D030FC30B830E730F330B330FC30C9\X0,,'), IFCTEXT('CGRYCODE,50052000000000,\X2\6A5F56685206985E30B330FC30C9\X0,,'), IFCTEXT('NAME2,\X2\6D88706B30DD30F330D7\X0,\X2\578B5F0F540D79F0\X0,,'), IFCTEXT('NAME1,100X80(50Hz/\X2\4E0976F8\X0\200V/18.5kW)'',\X2\30E130FC30AB30FC578B756A\X0,,')), $); #1080 = IFCPROPERTYSET('1lp$ftNHnDC9c3cN6U7A7q', #1044, 'Pset_BE-Bridge_EquipmentData', $, (#1078, #1079));

＃１０７９IFCTEXT('NAME1,100X80(50Hz/\X2\4E0976F8\X0\200V/18.5kW)'',\X2\30E130FC30AB30FC578B756A\X0,,')), $);

Comment: Which conversion method did you use for this model? Could you share a test model to `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`? It would be nice to have a test model for investigation.